# npm run install not completing when i run docker build command

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, devops

I'm dockerizing a node application , then  on initial set up of the docker file and running  **docker build -t nodeapp .** it fails to install the node packages and exits with code: 1 .Results from terminal

[image: Error from the terminal]
Here is my docker file

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./ /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm" ,"run" ,"start"]
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  What is the actual error that's being produced?

Comment: npm install is not working ,in short in doesn't install the required dependancies

Answer (score 0):

What is the Base image here you have used?

Use, Base Image as node:alpine or node:16.18.1 and try to build and run in locally

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 5001
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```